# Как передать List на jsp(Spring)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Доброго времени суток. Я новичёк в Spring. Мне необходимо написать программу используя RESTful интерфейс. Контроллер:

```
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> getAll(){
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
    return userService.getUserById(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addNewUser(User user){
    userService.addUser(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void delUser(User user){
    userService.deleteUser(user);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updUser(User user){
    userService.updateUser(user);
}
```

Бин

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private Date dateOfBirth;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "info")
private String info;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;
```

Мне надо теперь выводить информацию на jsp ну и наоборот. Пока хотя бы getAll(). Помогите люди добрые советом как это сделать)

Comment: Вам явно нужно инициализировать модель на конкретный параметр в странице, к примеру Model m = new Model(); m.setObject("list", userRepo.getAllUsers());

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers());
    return "all_users";
}
```

all_users - имя вашей jsp-вьюхи

Comment: На jsp не выводит                                              
 @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAll(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "main";
    }      

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>${user.id}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Помогите вызвать это всё удовольствие в jsp файле

Comment: Какую-то ошибку выдает? Может быть лист уже пустым приходит на вью?

Comment: Ниже моя вьюха. Я передаю в инпуты мои данные о юзере потом изменяю и должен сохнанить. изменить это пут. Но вывести на вьюху это пост. И вьюха не видит пут.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:form method="put" action="/users/update" commandName="user">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="surname">
            <spring:message text="Фамилия"/>
        </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="surname" value='${user.surname}'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="login">
            <spring:message text="Логин"/>
        </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="login" value='${user.login}'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="password">
            <spring:message text="Пароль"/>
        </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="password" value='${user.password}'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="info">
            <spring:message text="О себе"/>
        </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="info" value='${user.info}'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="address">
            <spring:message text="Адрес"/>
        </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="address" value='${user.address}'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                               value="<spring:message text="Изменить"/>"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```